# Core Data Relationship Mappings: Double Quotes in Value Expression are automatically turned into single quotes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-migration

After generating a Mapping Model for a Core Data Migration, all Value Expressions for the relationship mapping are generated correctly except 1 Value Expression, where the arguments have single quotes (') instead of double quotes ("). This results in a parsing error.

This is what I would expect:

```
FUNCTION($manager ,"destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , "MatchToMatch" , $source.matches)
```

But this is how the function expression is generated:

```
FUNCTION($manager ,'destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:' , 'MatchToMatch' , $source.matches)
```

[A specific Value Expression is always generated with single quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a84mm.png)

When I change the "Source Fetch" option in the right sidebar to "Use Custom(...)" and enter the expression manually, all double quotes are turned back into single quotes.

When I change the Value Expression directly in the Mapping Editor table, I get the following error message:

> *Unable to parse the format string "FUNCTION($manager >,"destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , >"MatchToMatch" , $source.matches) == 1"*

When I build and run a migration, I get the following error message:

> *2016-01-27 10:30:33.875 mapc[1431:352140] *** Terminating app due to >uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse >the format string "FUNCTION($manager >,'destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:' , >'MatchToMatch' , $source.matches) == 1"'*

Can someone explain, what is happening and how I can come around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that matches is a reserved keyword.

Reserved keywords:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Check the note described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html

Comment: That was my case, thanks!
also note that keywords are case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to remove broken relationship
2. Add new one with empty "Value Expression"
   [Look here](http://www.screencast.com/t/4op6YhzqCR)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.